# How to start Epsa Diagnostics for a Windows 10 based Dell Laptop?

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron, diagnostic

I'm having trouble with some hardware due to which I am trying to start the Epsa diagnostics which is usually accessed from tapping the F12 key at the time of Boot at the dell Logo.But now after the update to Windows 10 I'm clueless as to how Is Epsa started on Windows 10

I have also tried the Online Diagnostic tool from the dell.com site but there for a complete Diagnostic test it crossed the standard time to complete the test and it continues above 1hr even If I ignore the time.

Comment: You should also be able to get to diagnostics from the BIOS/EFI firmware as well (F2 at boot, should be on last page with exit/save options)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to still access the Dell Diagnostics straight from the boot menu, just hit F12 as soon as the laptop receives power, press it multiple times instead of worrying about timing. I had a client ask a similar question and as far as I could tell from her laptop Dell simply hasn't made their online diagnostics tool 100% compatible with Windows 10, though I have no doubt that will be corrected. If you can be specific about the model and hardware you are having issue with, I can offer better advice.

Comment: Its with the battery component.I tried pressing the F12 several times but it did not open ,The problem is that the battery gets dead even after charging it to 100%.I hardly use the battery because I am plugged in most of the time.Its the new Dell Inspiron 7000 series

Comment: Press and hold F12 while powering up, continue to hold until you get beeps or Epsa loads, then let up.